# WebStorm, "surround with" removes newlines

Tags: javascript, webstorm

When I use the "Surround with" functionality in WebStorm 9.0.2, it removes all newlines in the selected code.
The same happens when I type "}" to close a block of existing code.

How to tell WebStorm to only indent the code, but leave the existing formatting alone. I'll also be satisfied if I could change or downright disable this auto-format behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is auto-formatted when expanding Live Templates by default (this is controlled by `Reformat according to style` which is set for each template individually). Also, the code is auto-formatted on adding a brace if `Reformat block on typing '}'` (Settings | Editor | General | Smart keys) is enabled. You can, of course, disable all mentuioned options... But I'd rather suggest configuring code style settings so that the line breaks are preserved on code reformatting